# How to insert a new row into table when a query returns no rows atomically in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, atomic

I'm writing a django app. I want to insert a new row into a table if there are no rows meet a specific condition. For example:

```
if not SomeModel.objects.filter(in_use=True).exist():
    new_using = SomeModel(start_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), in_use=True)
    new_using.save()
```

I want the above code to be atomic so that there won't be more than one row having `in_use=True` in the table. I learned that django had an atomic() context manager. So I'm considering to do this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
   if not SomeModel.objects.filter(in_use=True).exist():
        new_using = SomeModel(start_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), in_use=True)
        new_using.save()
```

I'm not very familiar with SQL so I want to know if the above code can make sure that there will be no more than one rows in the table having the `in_use=True` at the same time? If not, what's the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add unique constraint to `SomeModel` table in database. For example in postgres (how to do it in other databases https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/how-to-implement-a-default-flag-that-can-only-be-set-on-a-single-row):

```
create unique index inuseuniq on somemodel (in_use) where in_use;
```

and then react appropriately on `IntegrityError`:

```
try:
    # exist() query not needed
    new_using = SomeModel.objects.create(start_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                                         in_use=True)
except IntegrityError:
    # someone already using SomeModel data
    # try again or report to user
```

Answer (score 0):

`transaction.atomic()` ensures that your block of code runs in a database transaction; unfortunately, a database transaction will not in general protect you from creating two conflicting rows like this. Your case is similar to the notoriously hard `UPSERT` problem. See [this article](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/) for more about why this is a tricky issue.

The way to make this work is going to be database-dependent, and I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to advise you. The general approach would be to either acquire a table lock or use the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level, but there may be better solutions offered by your database.